# vimtex conceal options and character substitution not working on Windows

Tags: plugin-vimtex

I wanted to write and edit a .tex document as fast as possible, so I followed [this guide](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/), but I can't get vimtex to work properly. I would like to have Vim hide characters like `$`,`\[` and replace some commands like `\bigcap` with `∩`. I don't care about compiling, I use Overleaf for that, I would just like to have a smooth and fast way to edit tex files. I hope someone can kindly help me.

A screenshot of my Vim window:

[image]

And this is my `_vimrc` file:

```
filetype off
set shellslash
set rtp+=~\Vim\vimfiles\bundle\Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin('Vim/vimfiles/bundle')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

Plugin 'lervag/vimtex'
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
"let g:vimtex_view_method='zathura' DEACTIVATED because I don't need it
let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
set conceallevel=1
let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Just to rule out any other confounding factors, [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't think that any of that is helpful in my case.

Comment: Actually, youve got a vimrc posted with irrelevant (we hope) code. If you can use those instructions to narrow down on a minimal vimrc that still reproduces your issue, it would make finding the problem that much easier. (You can [edit] once you find said minimal vimrc)

Comment: I changed the vimrc. I can't reduce it further because I am a noob, sorry.

Comment: Did you read the comments on the page you linked. Looks like others had issues related to conceal and there are some suggestions there. For example: "the conceal should be fixed by adding `hi Conceal ctermbg=none` to your vimrc". Perhaps one of those is about the same issue.

Comment: Yes I tried that and other suggestions but they didn't work.

Comment: FYI if you found a solution you should post it as an answer rather than edit the question. (It's perfectly fine to post an answer to your own question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By tweaking the `_vimrc` file I have managed to determine the likely cause of the issue: the (missing) setting `set encoding=utf-8`. Without it, neither the replacement of characters nor the concealment work.

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to write and edit a `.tex` document as fast as possible, so I followed this guide, but I can't get vimtex to work properly.

If you just want to edit a `.tex` document and not want to spend time learning tools, then I suggest you consider to use something like TeX maker. It should work well out of the box and the barrier to entry is very low.

If you want to use Vim with e.g. vimtex, you should expect to spend at least some time to learn to use the tools.

> I would like to have Vim hide characters like $,[ and replace some commands like \bigcap with ∩. I don't care about compiling, I use Overleaf for that, I would just like to have a smooth and fast way to edit tex files. I hope someone can kindly help me.

This is actually not a part of vimtex ([yet](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/pull/1834)). Vimtex has so far relied on the syntax plugin developed by Dr. Chip, which provides the highlighting and conceal support. Vimtex have provided some additional improvements on the syntax, especially with regard to various packages.

So, my point is that your problem is not vimtex specific, but rather Vim (or neovim) specific.

> And this is my _vimrc file: ...

I think the answer to your question is that you need to specify `let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'` to ensure that the filetype for `tex` files is `tex` (and not `plaintex`). In your screenshot, it seems you are looking at a minimal LaTeX file like this:

```
\[
    \bigcup
\]
```

Without specifying `g:tex_flavor`, such a file will be detected as a plaintex file, and so the conceal and syntax support will be very minimal.

Comment: That’s actually already in the vimrc, as far as i can tell.

Comment: I decided to use Vim because, if that guide I linked is correct, it can be much more efficient and practical than other methods. But that guide is intended for more advanced Vim and Linux users, so it's been quite misleading for me. For example, according to the guide it is vimtex that does the concealment. Is Dr. Chip syntax plugin integrated in vimtex? Also, I had already added `g:tex_flavor` to my `_vimrc`.

Comment: I solved it, look at the edit. Apparently I had to add KeitaNakamura concealment plugin?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Strange, I didn't notice that line in the vimrc before.

Comment: @TheFootprint Yes, Vim can be a very efficient and practical tool, but it does take time to learn it properly. As a long time user I can strongly recommend it, but you should be aware it takes investment to learn how to use it. There is not really any shortcuts, you just have to take it step by step.
  Reg. vimtex and syntax: Vimtex has traditionally integrated around Dr. Chips syntax plugin. This is changing in the relatively near future, though.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Lervag, and thank you for writing vimtex by the way. I think the mistake was probably the missing line `set encoding=utf-8`, very hard to notice I believe.